# Like Button Alignment woes

Tags: php, html, css, button, facebook-like

I'm currently re-designing the layout of my site and am trying to position my Facebook like button on the bottom of my page, next to my 'Tweet' button... However there seems to be a five pixel difference between the top and bottom of each button, knocking them out of alignment... I've tried setting the padding and the margin of the  div to 0 but this hasn't worked either...

The page can be seen here: http://www.jameshenry.info/test/video.php?video=14

Any ideas on why the tops of each button are not aligned?

Comment: Tags - should this be php, HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
<div class="bottombar">
  <div style="float:left">
    <iframe class="twitter-share-button ......
  </div>
  <div class="float:left">
    <fb:like ........
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to work - Thanks! Any way to align on the right hand side of the page? I've tried using float:right but am left with a gap between the two buttons!

Comment: keep the float: right; (order gets reversed) but add in a margin-right:-5px for the item on the left side (should be the fb:like's DIV)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't much that can be done, the size seems to vary along with the padding and margin across every browser. You can set a container to a specific size and overflow to hidden but then it will cut parts of the button off in one browser but not another.

Not much help, I know, but I wouldn't waste too much time on it.

One approach I've taken is to create a nice share button and have them both appear in a tooltip on hover. At least then the ugliness is hidden until needed!

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>
Azari & III - James Henry
</title>
<link href="scripts/page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class = 'rightbar'>
<div class = 'videobox'>
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/28767067?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe><BR><div class='video-title'>Azari & III</div><div class='video-subtitle'>Manic (Directors Cut)</div><BR><div class='back'><a href="./">&laquo;back</a></div></div>
</div>
<div class ='bottombar'>
    <div style="margin: 3px 3px 0px 3px; position: relative; float: left;"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
    <div style="margin: 3px 3px 0px 3px; position: relative; float: left;"><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like show_faces="false" layout="box_count" width="75" padding="0" margin="0" font="lucida grande" !important ></fb:like></div>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```